# Changing the design of a field of vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, scipy

I've written a script which calculates the flow of the water in a bog with the following scripts.
Below the script I have first posted what my plot looks like followed by what I would like to change the design to.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')


df = pd.read_csv('/mnt/sd-card/Dropbox/Documents/exjobb/wgs-points1.csv')


K = 1*10**-7.23 #Soil resistance constant
A = 1 #cross section (m²)


tree = cKDTree(df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']].values)


net_flow_vectors = []
magnitudes = []


for i in range(len(df)):
    
    neighbors = tree.query_ball_point(df.loc[i, ['x', 'y']].values, r=0.00005)
    
    
    flow_vectors = []
    for j in neighbors:
        if i != j:
            x_diff = df.loc[i, 'x'] - df.loc[j, 'x']
            y_diff = df.loc[i, 'y'] - df.loc[j, 'y']
            distance = np.sqrt(x_diff**2 + y_diff**2)
            Q = -K * A * (df.loc[i, 'z'] - df.loc[j, 'z']) / distance
            flow_vectors.append(Q * np.array([x_diff, y_diff]))
    
    
    net_flow_vector = sum(flow_vectors)
    net_flow_vectors.append(net_flow_vector)
    
    
    magnitude = np.linalg.norm(net_flow_vector)
    magnitudes.append(magnitude)
    

net_flow_vectors = np.array(net_flow_vectors)
magnitudes = np.array(magnitudes)


magnitudes = (magnitudes - magnitudes.min()) / (magnitudes.max() - magnitudes.min())


q = plt.quiver(df['x'], df['y'], net_flow_vectors[:,0], net_flow_vectors[:,1], magnitudes, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(q, label='Flow Magnitude')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

### `wgs-points1.csv`

```
z,x,y
144.16817000,13.546924,56.265829
144.17050000,13.546940,56.265830
144.17286000,13.546956,56.265830
144.17526000,13.546972,56.265830
144.17770000,13.546988,56.265830
144.18018000,13.547004,56.265830
144.18269000,13.547020,56.265831
144.18524000,13.547037,56.265831
144.18782000,13.547053,56.265831
144.19043000,13.547069,56.265831
144.19308000,13.547085,56.265831
144.19577000,13.547101,56.265832
144.19849000,13.547117,56.265832
144.16420000,13.546924,56.265820
144.16654000,13.546940,56.265821
144.16892000,13.546956,56.265821
144.17133000,13.546972,56.265821
144.17379000,13.546989,56.265821
144.17627000,13.547005,56.265821
144.17880000,13.547021,56.265822
144.18136000,13.547037,56.265822
144.18396000,13.547053,56.265822
144.18660000,13.547069,56.265822
144.18926000,13.547085,56.265822
144.19197000,13.547101,56.265823
144.19471000,13.547117,56.265823
144.16017000,13.546924,56.265811
144.16252000,13.546941,56.265812
144.16491000,13.546957,56.265812
144.16735000,13.546973,56.265812
144.16981000,13.546989,56.265812
144.17232000,13.547005,56.265812
144.17486000,13.547021,56.265813
144.17744000,13.547037,56.265813
144.18005000,13.547053,56.265813
144.18271000,13.547069,56.265813
144.18539000,13.547086,56.265813
144.18811000,13.547102,56.265814
144.19087000,13.547118,56.265814
144.15609000,13.546925,56.265802
144.15845000,13.546941,56.265803
144.16086000,13.546957,56.265803
144.16330000,13.546973,56.265803
144.16579000,13.546989,56.265803
144.16831000,13.547005,56.265803
144.17087000,13.547021,56.265804
144.17346000,13.547038,56.265804
144.17609000,13.547054,56.265804
144.17876000,13.547070,56.265804
144.18147000,13.547086,56.265804
144.18421000,13.547102,56.265805
144.18699000,13.547118,56.265805
144.15195000,13.546925,56.265794
144.15433000,13.546941,56.265794
144.15675000,13.546957,56.265794
144.15921000,13.546973,56.265794
144.16171000,13.546990,56.265794
144.16424000,13.547006,56.265794
144.16682000,13.547022,56.265795
144.16943000,13.547038,56.265795
144.17208000,13.547054,56.265795
144.17477000,13.547070,56.265795
144.17749000,13.547086,56.265795
144.18025000,13.547102,56.265796
144.18305000,13.547118,56.265796
144.14775000,13.546925,56.265785
144.15014000,13.546942,56.265785
144.15258000,13.546958,56.265785
144.15505000,13.546974,56.265785
144.15757000,13.546990,56.265785
144.16012000,13.547006,56.265785
144.16271000,13.547022,56.265786
144.16534000,13.547038,56.265786
144.16801000,13.547054,56.265786
144.17072000,13.547070,56.265786
144.17346000,13.547087,56.265786
144.17624000,13.547103,56.265787
144.17906000,13.547119,56.265787
144.14349000,13.546926,56.265776
144.14590000,13.546942,56.265776
144.14835000,13.546958,56.265776
144.15084000,13.546974,56.265776
144.15337000,13.546990,56.265776
144.15594000,13.547006,56.265777
144.15855000,13.547022,56.265777
144.16120000,13.547039,56.265777
144.16389000,13.547055,56.265777
144.16662000,13.547071,56.265777
144.16938000,13.547087,56.265777
144.17218000,13.547103,56.265778
144.17502000,13.547119,56.265778
144.13918000,13.546926,56.265767
144.14160000,13.546942,56.265767
144.14407000,13.546958,56.265767
144.14658000,13.546974,56.265767
144.14912000,13.546991,56.265767
144.15171000,13.547007,56.265768
144.15434000,13.547023,56.265768
144.15700000,13.547039,56.265768
144.15971000,13.547055,56.265768
144.16246000,13.547071,56.265768
144.16524000,13.547087,56.265768
144.16806000,13.547103,56.265769
144.17092000,13.547120,56.265769
144.13481000,13.546926,56.265758
144.13724000,13.546943,56.265758
144.13972000,13.546959,56.265758
144.14225000,13.546975,56.265758
144.14481000,13.546991,56.265758
144.14742000,13.547007,56.265759
144.15006000,13.547023,56.265759
144.15275000,13.547039,56.265759
144.15547000,13.547055,56.265759
144.15824000,13.547072,56.265759
144.16104000,13.547088,56.265760
144.16389000,13.547104,56.265760
144.16677000,13.547120,56.265760
144.13037000,13.546927,56.265749
144.13282000,13.546943,56.265749
144.13532000,13.546959,56.265749
144.13786000,13.546975,56.265749
144.14044000,13.546991,56.265749
144.14306000,13.547007,56.265750
144.14573000,13.547023,56.265750
144.14843000,13.547040,56.265750
144.15118000,13.547056,56.265750
144.15397000,13.547072,56.265750
144.15679000,13.547088,56.265751
144.15966000,13.547104,56.265751
144.16256000,13.547120,56.265751
144.12587000,13.546927,56.265740
144.12834000,13.546943,56.265740
144.13085000,13.546959,56.265740
144.13341000,13.546975,56.265740
144.13601000,13.546992,56.265740
144.13865000,13.547008,56.265741
144.14133000,13.547024,56.265741
144.14406000,13.547040,56.265741
144.14683000,13.547056,56.265741
144.14963000,13.547072,56.265741
144.15248000,13.547088,56.265742
144.15537000,13.547104,56.265742
144.15830000,13.547121,56.265742
144.12131000,13.546927,56.265731
144.12379000,13.546944,56.265731
144.12632000,13.546960,56.265731
144.12890000,13.546976,56.265731
144.13151000,13.546992,56.265731
144.13418000,13.547008,56.265732
144.13688000,13.547024,56.265732
144.13963000,13.547040,56.265732
144.14241000,13.547056,56.265732
144.14524000,13.547073,56.265732
144.14811000,13.547089,56.265733
144.15102000,13.547105,56.265733
144.15397000,13.547121,56.265733
144.11668000,13.546928,56.265722
144.11918000,13.546944,56.265722
144.12173000,13.546960,56.265722
144.12432000,13.546976,56.265722
144.12696000,13.546992,56.265722
144.12964000,13.547008,56.265723
144.13236000,13.547025,56.265723
144.13513000,13.547041,56.265723
144.13794000,13.547057,56.265723
144.14079000,13.547073,56.265723
144.14369000,13.547089,56.265724
144.14662000,13.547105,56.265724
144.14959000,13.547121,56.265724
```

Comment: Too vague. What specifically about the first plot is missing when compared to the second that you care about? A non unidirectional vector field? A heatmap?

Comment: It's the heatmap I'm referring to yes. I want it to be like a background.

Comment: @TobiasBowley Did my solution answer your question? If so, you should accept the answer rather than leaving the question without an accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, no it didn't. I've simply been too busy elsewhere to answer here. Thanks though! I ended up settling with what I had.

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the plot, you can first us `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` for the background colors and then plot the vector field on top of that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

U = X + 2*Y
V = -Y

magnitudes = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
scaled_magnitudes = (magnitudes - magnitudes.min())/(magnitudes.max() - magnitudes.min())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
p = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, scaled_magnitudes, cmap="hsv")
ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, orientation="horizontal")
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

[image]